# Ubuntu freezes on startup after update (18.04.3 LTS)

Tags: 18.04, updates

I am dual booting windows 10 and Ubuntu, and have had no problems after installing the first time until I attempted to update a web browser last night using 'sudo apt-get update Brave'. This appeared to have updated everything, not just the browser.
Despite that, everything worked fine last night post installation. I used it and shut it down as usual.
However, when I attempted to boot up this morning it just hangs up at the splash screen right after the mouse cursor appears at the bottom right of the screen.
I'm at a loss as to what to do.

If it helps I'm using an AMD Ryzen 5 2500U processor.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research this morning, I came across an article that described similar issues with the same version. I had to edit the grub file using `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and add 'nomodeset' to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` line.
I had to do something similar while installing before, but I guess maybe something changed during the accidental update.
Anyway, that seems to be working for now. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Here is the page I drew from:
https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln306327/manual-nomodeset-kernel-boot-line-option-for-linux-booting?lang=en